# Install original ssd in in place of the DVD drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, dvd

I have a MacBock Pro 2012 no retina. Would like **to move** my **500 crucial ssd** to **dvd drive** and insert a hybrid HDD as data storage into the drive where the SSD is now.

I bought this:

[image]

To replace SSD I would follow the [IFix](https://it.ifixit.com/Guida/Installazione+dell%27SSD+Dual+Drive+nel+MacBook+Pro+Unibody+da+13-Inch+versione+met%C3%A0+2009/8518) guide

I would like to avoid reinstalling everything and then use the SSD in which the Operating System is already installed.
Is it possible or am I forced to reinstall the operating system?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way, rather than simply install the new HDD in the optical disk drive caddy and leave the SSD where it is?

Comment: @gronostaj because the optical disk slot is faster and I would like to put the SO in the faster drive. for this reason I just want to change the position of the existing SSD

Comment: Is it actually? Usually it's the other way around: main bay is SATA3 and ODD bay is SATA2 because optical disks are way, way slower. I doubt Apple would use an unnecessarily fast link for ODD and a slower one for main bay.

Comment: @gronostaj so why does everyone install the boot disk into the optical disk and say it's faster?

Comment: @gronostaj I have read something about it and I think I will follow your suggestion.
I leave the crucial SSD in its slot and instead of the optical drive I insert a 1GB Segate SSHD (W7712E9X).
I thought I would do either a FAT 32 or NTFS format for this SSHD to use as storage data

Comment: @gronostaj or install another crucial mx500?

Comment: Are you using macOS, Windows or Linux? What are you going to use it for (more specifically than "storage")?

Comment: @gronostaj I only use macOS and rarely a virtual machine. The new disk is for storage only

Comment: What kind of storage? Large files, like movies or ISOs? Many tiny files? VM disks? How are you going to use these files? Why do you want to use FAT32 or NTFS if you don't need portability?

Comment: @gronostaj  the purpose of the second disk is that of data storage and I will also put virtual machines.
maybe I would like to make two 500 partitions and one dedicated to backup the SO, even if I hate "Time Machine" because it doesn't allow a selective backup

Comment: @gronostaj 
I was planning to create a 500 APFS partition (backup) and an NTFS (data only) partition because the partition is more easily recoverable in case of failure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120315/discussion-between-gronostaj-and-antonio).